# How to keep private images private

Tags: php, json, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I have some Users in my API Service Authenticating with OAuth, via a Web Client (website).

When the User requests their private profile images.. how should these be served up?  I see a few options few drawbacks and unsure what's the best decision going forward.

**1) host the images with a hashed name...** eg (`~/public/folder/309dsfas928f39rjkfe93.jpg`)

**Pro** 
   - Simple, keeps all assets centralized to the Apigility based server.
  **Con**
   - nothing preventing something from finding an image .. no of assuring access control once a URL is found.

**2) pass back the img data in a JSON request**

**Pro**
   - You're assured that the person receiving an image has permission.. every time the image is accessed
  **Con**
   - now images need to be stored (temporarily?) on the WebClient's server.. 
   - images traveling in JSON seems wrong to me

Are there datastreaming options instead?  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Nice question!

Right now I have a solution where I pass the image in a `base64` encoded sting in the json response. This works nicely and on the client side you can quickly paste the string in the `src` tag of the html image. So when it comes to workflow it is very smooth.

But I guess others might have something to say about this solution :P

Comment: Thanks for sharing Wilt, I guess we're going to punt on this problem for the time being.  We see most people going the first style.. but it's worth a look how to securely serve images.